# Document library with only owner access using PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, pnp-powershell, hub-site

Using PnP PowerShell, I would like to create an extra document library in SharePoint Online, where only the owner group has access. With the script below I am able to remove all groups I want to remove, except "Hub Visitors".

How can I get to the point where only the owner group has access to the document library?

```
$InternalDocumentsLibraryName = "Internal Docs"
New-PnPList -Title InternalDocumentsLibraryName -Template DocumentLibrary

$MemberGroupName = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedMemberGroup
$VisitorGroupName = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedVisitorGroup


$InternalDocuments = Get-PnPList -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName
 
If($InternalDocuments)
{
       
    Set-PnPList -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName -BreakRoleInheritance -CopyRoleAssignments
    Set-PnPListPermission -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName -Group $MemberGroupName -RemoveRole 'Edit'
    Set-PnPListPermission -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName -Group $VisitorGroupName -RemoveRole 'Read'
}
Else
{   
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Could not find '$InternalDocumentsLibraryName'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
//Email address of user running PowerShell
$userEmail = "abc@contoso.com"

$InternalDocumentsLibraryName = "Internal Docs"
New-PnPList -Title InternalDocumentsLibraryName -Template DocumentLibrary

$OwnersGroupName = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedOwnerGroup

$InternalDocuments = Get-PnPList -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName 

If($InternalDocuments)
{
       
    Set-PnPList -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName -BreakRoleInheritance
    Set-PnPListPermission -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName -Group $OwnersGroupName -AddRole 'Full Control'
    Set-PnPListPermission -Identity $InternalDocumentsLibraryName -User $userEmail -RemoveRole 'Full Control'
}
Else
{   
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Could not find '$InternalDocumentsLibraryName'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to connect the site to the hub as a last step, not as a first step. Then "Hub Visitors" will not be added, so then there is no need to remove this group.